# Save android studio activity on separate file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I had created a bulky activity and now I need to modify a lot in it. I decided to first copy paste the entire code on text box but I do not think it is the right way. I want to save the activity consisting of xml file and .java file in a single file that can be recalled if required. Is this possible or should I copy and paste both file to some location manually.
Thanks

Comment: If you're using Git or a similar version control system (VCS) you could go back to a commit at any point. If you're not yet familiar with VCS you should probably just copy it to some save location.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Software development it is often a good practice to use some kind of version control system.

A lot of people are using systems based on git like GitLab, GitHub, BitBucket etc. 
These tools help to manage your source code in different versions and enable you to switch between versions easily.

In your case you could decide to work with github and after pushing your project you could compare your recent code with the new one until you decide your refactoring is done.

If you decide to dive into this you find many tutorials with google.
e.G https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-git